# Tab Bar Disappears

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uistoryboard, tabbarcontroller

I'm new to iOS Development and I'm having problems with Controllers. I have simplified my problem to make everyone's life easier.

So here's the set up:
The root view is Tab Bar Controller which has 2 tabs, View A and View B

View A launches the camera after it's done with the camera, dismisses the camera and then goes to another view called View C, now View C is **not** in the tab bar.

There is a button in View C when clicked it dismisses the current view and goes to View B.
Here's the problem: When I try to load from View C to View B tab bar dissapears.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

View C is only useful after taking the picture so adding it to the tab bar is not a solution.

Thanks

**EDIT:** 
Here's the code of how I'm Passing data between the tabs:

**How I call View C from View A:**

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:
 ^{
     UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
     ViewControllerA *A = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerA"];
     A.data1 = data1; 
     A.data2 = data2; 
     A.image = image; 
     [self presentViewController:A animated:YES completion:nil];
 }];
```

**How I call View B from View C:**

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

{

```
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toViewB"]) {

    SomeClass *obj = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
    [obj setData1: _data1];
    [obj setData2: _data2.text];
    [obj setImage: _image];


    ViewControllerB *B = (ViewControllerB *)segue.destinationViewController;
    B.newObj = obj;
    [B createCell];
}
```

}

I also want to mention that the button I added to ViewB disappeared as well,

Comment: show you code how you are adding items to the TabBar , how you are displaying the View C & dismissing it?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Following is simple example for How can you use `UITabBarController`

Firsts Create all object of `UIViewController` and `UINavigationController` in `AppDelegate.h` file  and use following method of `AppDelegate.m`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window=[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds ]];

    self.viewCon=[[ViewController alloc] init];
    self.navCon=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewCon];
    self.navCon.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    self.viewCon.title=@"First View";

    self.fView=[[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    self.FnavCon=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.fView];
    self.FnavCon.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];

    self.fView.title=@"Secound View";

    self.sView=[[SecoundViewController alloc] init];
    self.SnavCon=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.sView];
    self.SnavCon.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    self.sView.title=@"Third View";
    .
    .
    // create UIViewController and UINavigationController As you need 
    .
    .
    .
    UIImage *img1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Australia.gif"];
    self.tbItem1=[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"First Page" image:img1 tag:1];
    self.viewCon.tabBarItem=self.tbItem1;

    UIImage *img2=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cameroon.gif"];
    self.tbItem2=[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Secound Page" image:img2 tag:2];
    self.fView.tabBarItem=self.tbItem2;

    UIImage *img3=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Canada.png"];
    self.tbItem3=[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Third Page" image:img3 tag:3];
    self.sView.tabBarItem=self.tbItem3;

    NSMutableArray *viewArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [viewArr addObject:self.navCon];
    [viewArr addObject:self.FnavCon];
    [viewArr addObject:self.SnavCon];


    self.tbCon=[[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tbCon.viewControllers=viewArr;

    [self.window addSubview:tbCon.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```